# if statement doesn't seem to ever fail

Tags: c, loops, boolean-logic

I have a loop which goes through an image stored in a buffer, grabs 1024 bytes at a time, and sends this kilobyte off as a UDP packet. Below is the relevant section of code.

Why doesn't my second if statement, `if (buf.bytesused - curr*1024 > 1024)` fail when `curr*1024` gets larger than `buf.bytesused`? I'm getting stuck in an infinite loop, which doesn't end until memcpy finally throws a seg fault. My buf.bytesused is around 900,000, but instead of looping about 900 times, it just keeps going, even when `buf.bytesused - curr*1024` gives a negative result, which is certainly less than 1024.

In case that wasn't clear: When curr is small, buf.bytesused - curr*1024 > 1024 is satisfied like I'd expect, and this second if-block is run. However, when curr get large (even so large that buf.bytesused - curr*1024 is negative), the second if-block is still being run, instead of the third block, after the else.

`buf.bytesused` is an unsigned 32 bit int.

```
  #define FRAME_START 0x0
  #define FRAME_END   0xF
  #define FRAME_MID   0xA

  uint_32 buf.bytesused = 921600;
  char frameInfo = FRAME_START;
  char frameNum = i;
  int curr = 0;

  while (frameInfo != FRAME_END) {
    if (curr == 0) {
      frameInfo = FRAME_START;
      memcpy(&frameInfo, &udpBuf[0], 1);
      memcpy(&frameNum, &udpBuf[1], 1);
      memcpy(buffers[buf.index].start + curr*1024, udpBuf + 2, 1024);
    }else if (buf.bytesused - curr*1024 > 1024) {
      frameInfo = FRAME_MID;
      memcpy(&frameInfo, &udpBuf[0], 1);
      memcpy(&frameNum, &udpBuf[1], 1);
      memcpy(buffers[buf.index].start + curr*1024, udpBuf + 2, 1024);
    } else {
      frameInfo = FRAME_END;
      memcpy(&frameInfo, &udpBuf[0], 1);
      memcpy(&frameNum, &udpBuf[1], 1);
      memcpy(buffers[buf.index].start + curr*1024, udpBuf + 2, (buf.bytesused % 1024));
    }

    if (sendto(s, udpBuf, BUFLEN, 0, &si_other, slen)==-1)
      diep("sendto()");
    curr++;
  }
```

As an aside, could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong with memcpy? It doesn't copy the values of my two chars to my buffer.

Comment: Are you sure the issue is with that if condition? It looks like you are overwriting `frameInfo` with whatever is in `udpBuf[0]`, meaning that it is highly unlikely to ever stay as `FRAME_END`. edit: oh, are those supposed to be the other way around? You might want to look at the parameter list for `memcpy` and see if you are using it correctly

Comment: Is `buf.bytesused` a `size_t` or other unsigned integer type? If so, the subtraction will be done using unsigned arithmetic, and won't ever go negative.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear in the question. I hope this is more clear: When `curr` is small, `buf.bytesused - curr*1024 > 1024` is satisfied like I'd expect, and this second if-block is run. However, when `curr` get large (even so large that `buf.bytesused - curr*1024` is negative), the second if-block is still being run, instead of the third block, after the `else`.
I don't understand why, though in my experience it usually means I'm overlooking something very basic.

Comment: Please update the question to clarify it, rather than adding a comment.  You could provide some examples; you could also provide definitions (type information) for the variables in the question.

Comment: Post the rest of your code so we can see how you've implemented the buffers. No one knows what `buf.bytesused` means.

Comment: Sorry guys, I should have known better. I will update this in a few minutes.

Comment: I'm working on making a minimal working example. In the meantime, the entire code is here if anyone wants to take a look: http://pastebin.com/MSvpUxLQ

Comment: @WhiteHotLoveTiger: Edited the solution. Please see, if it can help you.

Comment: I fixed all the memcpy mistakes I had (source & destination were reversed -- and I had even checked them in the man pages, though I must have been half asleep when I did...). After making the proper memcpy calls, everything is suddenly working. When I print out the values of `buf.bytesused - curr*1024`, it goes nice and orderly, just as I would expect it to. I guess I must have been overwriting something with the improper call. In any event, the buf.bytesused value is indeed an unsigned 32 bit int.

Comment: Cast bytesused to signed before you do the computation.

Comment: @WhiteHotLoveTiger See my previous comment. It had nothing to do with your if statement, the problem is you were overwriting `frameInfo` with memcopy. In the future, make sure you've actually verified that your program is stuck in an if statement before you claim that it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case people are wondering, the actual problem is here:

```
frameInfo = FRAME_END;
memcpy(&frameInfo, &udpBuf[0], 1);
```

`frameInfo` is overwritten after it is set to `FRAME_END`, so `while (frameInfo != FRAME_END)` will never evaluate to false. The fact that this caused the program to enter an infinite loop lead the OP to mistakenly believe that his if statement was wrong. It's always good practice to use a debugger instead of assuming you know what the problem is!

Answer (score 4):

`if (buf.bytesused - curr*1024 > 1024) fail when curr*1024 gets larger than buf.bytesused`

It may be problem when `buf.bytesused` is `unsigned`.

If it is negative and signed, then the above comparison should fail.

To solve, you can use simple maths too.

```
if (buf.bytesused > curr*1024 + 1024)
```

or

```
if (buf.bytesused > (curr + 1)*1024)
```

These conditions will not cause problem due to sign unless `curr+1` is negative.

I think this should solve your problem.

Comment: This is highly unlikely to be the issue. Unless buf.bytesused is less than 1024, this condition will eventually fail EVEN if bytesused is unsigned. I don't think this is what's wrong.

Comment: @RedAlert - The unsigned result could be > 1024 right off the bat.

Comment: @Hot Licks - there is no "result" in his code, but if you are talking about bytesused, then it should work fine if it starts > 1024. As curr increments, eventually the expression will evaluate to something between 0 and 1024, which will cause the condition to fail.

Comment: Sorry I didn't have this information from the beginning, but I've updated the question to indicate that buf.bytesused is an unsigned 32 bit int, with an initial value of 921600.

Comment: @RedAlert - I was talking about the result of the (possibly unsigned) subtraction.  All it takes is for curr to be 1 and bytesused to be < 1024.

Comment: @Hot Licks - Is that not exactly what I said initially?

Comment: @RedAlert - No, you said that unsigned arithmetic is unlikely to be the issue, when it's quite likely.

Comment: @Hot Licks - I opened with that potential race condition, and it IS unlikely. The actual value is orders of magnitude bigger than 1024, so there's no chance of this ever being a problem. The checkmark & upvotes on this answer will only confuse people, since it has nothing to do with OP's issue.

Comment: @RedAlert - Who mentioned a race condition??